# Mysql Disable trigger during database recovery

Tags: mysql, triggers, backup, disaster-recovery

I need to recover a database with a data-only DB dump (made only of "insert").
I don't want to run triggers during this recovery, how can I do?

Answer (score 3):

If you have the option of recreating the dump, use the `--skip-triggers` option when running it. You will have to recreate the triggers afterwards, but it's a lot less painful.

[MySQL Trigger Docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_triggers)

Answer (score 2):

MySQL currently does not have this feature. Here are some links that may be of interest and give some ideas.

- [How to Disable/Enable Triggers on Demand](http://mysql-0v34c10ck.blogspot.com.es/2011/06/how-to-disableenable-triggers-on-demand.html)
- [WL#2825: Triggers: enable or disable](http://dev.mysql.com/worklog/task/?id=2825)

Also, if you have the ability, you can make:

1. Backup triggers only
2. Remove all triggers
3. Restore database
4. Create triggers again

It's more work, but a workaround to lack of feature.

Comment: How to backup triggers? May I use mysqldump?

Comment: @Tobia: Yes, [`mysqldump`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysqldump.html) is an option.